# Determine if flash OCX is installed?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

What is the best way to determine if the flash ocx is installed in Innosetup (or any installer for that matter).  I don't want to attempt to install it myself, I will simply force the user to go to the flash site and install, I just want to make sure that the flash.ocx (version 9+) is installed.

Is it enough to check for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash and check that CurVer >= 9?  Is there a better way to test for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function in the code section to check whether you can create an instance of the Flash control, like so:

```
function IsFlashInstalled(): boolean;
var
  V: Variant;
begin
  try
    V := CreateOleObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.9');
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Check out the various examples in the Inno Setup package on how to use your own function to show a message box to the user, cancel the installation, open the Flash site in the default browser or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way without Try/Except

```
function IsFlashInstalled: Boolean;
var ClassID : TCLSID;
begin
  Result := Succeeded(CLSIDFromProgID('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash', ClassID));//Use CreateComObject() instead...
end;
```